# How can I put dynamic content into the product description in Opencart3?

Tags: php, dynamic, summernote, opencart-3

I am trying to put dynamic data drawn from a database (or flat-file even if this would work better) into the description field of products in Opencart3, based on the local store that the customer will be visiting.

What I have done on a previous website is, using the nearest store id, pull the data specific for the product and store from a database and display it in the description

An trivial example is for the Description to say "ask for Joe" for shoppers near store A and "ask for Sarah" if the shoppers are near store B.

So I'm looking for a way to do that with Opencart 3.0.3.2 on an Ubuntu 18.04 server with PHP 7.2, Mariadb 10.1 (and PostgreSQL 10).

The standard editor (Summernote) removes PHP tags, though I've read that this may be configurable, but I can't see where. Summernote allows Javascript tags but that is client side so I cannot pull data from the database with that.

Any suggestions for configuring the editor to leave the PHP tags, or some other suggestion for retrieving the data and inserting it into the webpage, will be very gratefully received.

Comment: How are you differentiating between the "local stores"? Do you have multiple stores configured in a single OpenCart installation or do you have multiple OpenCart installs?

Comment: I have multiple store locations configured in a single OpenCart installation. I want to be able to use the product descriptions across all the store locations, with just the odd drop-in piece from the database where there is a difference between stores.

Answer (score 1):

I think your best option would be to work with the index action of the product controller: `/catalog/controller/product/product.php`

You'll need to get your current `store_id`:

```
$store_id = $this->config->get('config_store_id');
```

And then edit this line to call another method that retrieves your data from the external database:

```
$data['description'] = html_entity_decode($product_info['description'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
```

Best practise here would be to add a new method to the product model in the file `\catalog\model\catalog\product.php`

Create a new method:

```
public function getExternalDescription($store_id, $product_id) {
    // your logic here
}
```

Then have your product's controller file changed like this:

```
$data['description'] = $this->model_catalog_product->getExternalDescription($store_id, $product_id);
```

I would also suggest doing all of the above in an OCMOD or VQMOD rather than changing the core files. More on this here: [OCMOD Wiki](https://github.com/opencart/opencart/wiki/Modification-System)